# How to add grammar to default VoiceDialer App?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am trying to add a few commands to android default voicedialer app. It has commands like Open, dial, call, redial etc, I want to include lets say 'Find' to it. I have downloaded the source code from [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/VoiceDialer.git;a=tree) and compiled it in Eclipse. the application sets up Grammar for arguments of these commands like it stores the names and phone numbers of the persons in contact list to generate intents when their names are recognized for CALL JOHN voice command. For CALL in this command it is just comparing the first word of resulting recognized string to "CALL".

I added "FIND" as an extra else if condition in the onRecognitionSuccess() function as shown below:

```
public class CommandRecognizerEngine extends RecognizerEngine 
{
 ............
 protected  void onRecognitionSuccess(RecognizerClient recognizerClient) throws InterruptedException 
 {
  .....................
  if ("DIAL".equalsIgnoreCase(commands[0])) 
        {
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("tel", commands[1], null);
            String num =  formatNumber(commands[1]);
            if (num != null) 
            {
                addCallIntent(intents, uri, literal.split(" ")[0].trim() + " " + num, "", 0);
            }
        }
    ................
    else if ("FIND".equalsIgnoreCase(commands[0])) 
        {
            if (Config.LOGD) 
                Log.d(TAG, "FIND detected...");
        }
  }//end onRecognitionSuccess
 }//end CommandRecognizerEngine
```

but my app can't recognize it. Does anyone know how does recognizer detects commands like OPEN or CALL etc or refer me to appropriate documentation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been over a year, I doubt you need this answer anymore.  However, some other people might find this through Google, as I did.

Right now, the best way to apply grammars to speech recognition on Android is to set the number of results higher, and then filter the results based on your grammar.  It is not perfect, as the word recognized may not have passed a threshold to be included in the list, but it does greatly improve the accuracy of all speech recognition applications where the types of things you can say are somewhat limited.

Comment: Thanks SeniorA. Though I am not using it now but you are right, it makes sense.